# AWS EC2 t3.medium | Maven slow compile

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-ec2, maven-3

I'm currently using an EC2 t3.medium instance to compile a single module maven project. It is a project of 1500 Java classes.

The compilation should be very fast, usually about 2 minutes without testing. For some reason compilation is sometimes very slow and takes between 9 and 10 minutes. The maven command used is:

```
mvn clean compile -U -Dmaven.skip.test=true -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dsource.skip=true -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dcobertura.skip=true -Dproject.reporting.outputEncoding=UTF-8 2>&1
```

The instance has no more processes running concurrently and cloudwatch indicates that CPU consumption is around 20%. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: t3 instances can run in burstable or unlimited mode. Under burstable mode, CPU is throttled when the CPU credit balance is exhausted. In unlimited mode, you just get charged extra. Check which your instance is configured for and check your CPU credit balance in cloudwatch.

Comment: In general, you should avoid t2/t3 instances for workloads that have constant CPU usage.

Comment: @jordanm According to cloudwatch that instance has 0.3 credits. The instance is always turned off and a script turns it on just for compiling and turns it off again. This seems to explain why in another instance t3.medium the project always compiles super fast (that instance has 600 credits) and that when the instance has been running for a long time then the compilation is also fast. What should I do to maintain good compilation times without increasing the price too much? Instances will be turned on and off automatically by a script in another instance.

Comment: @jordanm It is better to put them in unlimited mode considering that their natural state will be off? that mode increase the price a lot? Or better to change the instance type?
Thanks for the help. Consider writing your comment as an answer to give it the correct answer.

Comment: T3 instances do not receive **Launch credits** when started. They take time to gain credits for bursting. T2 instances, however, receive launch credits that _might_ be sufficient for your needs. However, only the first 100 launches of a T2 instance each day will receive launch credits. You might need to use a non-burstable instance type (eg M) for your use-case.

Comment: I've done tests and indeed my problem is caused by the credits, putting unlimited mode all compilations are very fast. I'm a bit lost on which instance I should use for this use case without significantly increasing the cost. I will think about the 3 options that you and jordanm have mentioned: 1- Unlimited mode. 2- T2 instance. 3- M instance. Thanks for help, @JohnRotenstein

Comment: T3 Unlimited mode has additional costs if you burst more than a given average (which will always be the case since you shutdown pretty quickly). If you launch less than 100 per day, T2 should be good. Otherwise, it's a tradeoff between T3 with Unlimited and a non-burstable Instance Type.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein EC2 will be launched less than 100 times a day so I'll start by testing with t2 instance. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have a single project which contains 1500 classes. That's already an issue. You should make a multi module project of it and cut it down to smaller parts (separation of concern on the module level)...That would also make it usable for `-T ..` option because single module project will not really be faster with `-T..` only unit tests (assumed to be configured in default way) will be run with multiple threads... Furthermore your configuration lacks some useful things like encoding sets correctly within the pom instead of giving that via CLI etc.

Comment: @un0tec It sounds like your use case is a good fit for spot instances. You can run a m5.large on spot at half the cost of t3.medium on-demand.